# A BoundedSemaphore in Python with the adjustable bound?

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore

I'm controlling a parallelized process which connects to a database (a limited IO resource) using a `threading.BoundedSemaphore`.

It works great, but at times another process is loading a database and I need to scale down (and later scale up again).

Afaik there is no way to change the semaphore bound on the fly, so I first join the threads and then relaunch with a new semaphore (having the adjusted bound). This works, but time is wasted on the join waiting.

Is there an implementation allowing to adjust the bound on the fly or any alternative?

Comment: It's a class (actually as subclass of `Semaphore`), so you should be able to derive your own subclass. Here's the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/threading.py#L469).

Comment: @martineau thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: FWIW, looks feasible to me.